# Installing R on Ubuntu - getting updates to work

Tags: r

I have installed R. However, when I update my system it complains that the R updates aren't authenticated.

What do I have to do to authenticate them?

Comment: Import the r repositroy gpg key. This section covers how to import the key - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication_Tab the r project should have a link to the key.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Would you consider adding that as an answer rather than a comment?

Comment: @coversnail added a better answer.

Answer (score 13):

From http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README:

> To obtain the latest R packages, add an entry like
>
> ```
> deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
> deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu oneiric/
> deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu natty/
> deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu lucid/
> deb http://<my.favorite.cran.mirror>/bin/linux/ubuntu hardy/
> ```
>
> in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, replacing
>   `<my.favorite.cran.mirror>` by the actual URL of your favorite CRAN
>   mirror. See http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html for the list of
>   CRAN mirrors.

Then later in the README

> The Ubuntu archives on CRAN are signed with the key of `Michael Rutter
>   <marutter@gmail.com>` with key ID E084DAB9. You can fetch
>   this key with
>
> ```
> gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
> ```
>
> and then feed it to `apt-key` with
>
> ```
> gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
> ```
>
> To install the complete R system, use
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install r-base
> ```

For additional details see

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Authentication_Tab

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt

Comment: There is still a problem: `W: Failed to fetch http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`   even with the line `deb http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu oneiric universe` in /etc/apt/sources.list. Tried other mirrors too (and `apt-get update` of course). Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Try another mirror http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Answer (score 1):

I just added a bunch of entries with `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` because finding one that works for oneiric is disappointing:

```
deb http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/ oneiric/

deb http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu oneiric/
deb http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/ oneiric/
deb http://streaming.stat.iastate.edu/CRAN/ oneiric/
deb http://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/ oneiric/
deb http://rweb.quant.ku.edu/cran/ oneiric/
deb http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.mtu.edu/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.wustl.edu/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.case.edu/ oneiric/
deb http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/cran/ oneiric/
deb http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.mirrors.hoobly.com oneiric/
deb http://mirrors.nics.utk.edu/cran/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com oneiric/
deb http://cran.fhcrc.org/ oneiric/
deb http://cran.cs.wwu.edu/ oneiric/
```

Then, type `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install r-base`

To get started with R, simply type `R` at the terminal prompt.  Quit with `q()`