# Trouble updating/installing newer required R

Tags: 11.10, apt, repository, r

All other [answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/131850/38636) I find only end up pointing to instructions: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/

So *interpreting* that site, added line:

```
deb http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu oneiric universe
```

to **/etc/apt/sources.list** and ran `apt-get update`.

(From experimentation I had to add the "universe" or "main" at the end to avoid parse error in the repositories list, preventing apt or synaptic from updating at all).

However the problem persists:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/oneiric/main/binary-i386/Packa‌​ges 404 Not Found
```

I enter that URL in a browser and clearly see that path is not there.  However this is: http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu/oneiric/ (under which the Packages file actually lies, etc.)

Tried other mirrors, same problem.

```
lsb_release -a
```

Ubuntu 11.10

The version of R available initially prevents me from installing updated packages, eg.:

```
> install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘PerformanceAnalytics’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line in /etc/apt/sources.list to

```
   deb http://r.meteo.uni.wroc.pl/bin/linux/ubuntu oneiric/
```

and retry

```
 apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks. That pushed it forward to: `dpkg: warning: files list file for package `python-twisted-core' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 246955 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace python-twisted-core 11.0.0-2 (using .../python-twisted-core_11.0.0-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement python-twisted-core ...
dpkg: ../../src/archives.c:985: tarobject: Assertion `r == stab.st_size' failed.`